# How to catch an untrapped exception? Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-7

my program is working in Windows XP, but crashes without any exception in windows 7. Try catch does not work. I also tried application.unhandledexception with no luck. Then I tried checking in windows administration and got the following log:

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category

Error   7/25/2011 11:25:14 AM   Application Error   1000    (100)   "Faulting application name: myApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4e2ce191

Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b96e

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x00052ca9

Faulting process id: 0x%9

Faulting application start time: 0x%10

Faulting application path: %11

Faulting module path: %12

Report Id: %13"
```

I'm not sure which part of the code to show as it has large collection classes, but I'll get back to editing this post.

I tried dumping files too from task manager, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Are there any particular tools I could use? I'm using VS2008. I looked into NLog, but I'm not sure what to do with it, so I skipped.

Any suggestions? tips and tricks?

Comment: Just to be certain, you are sure that the correct .NET framework is installed on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Yes it is installed in Windows 7. The NET framework version is 3.5 SP1 @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen

Comment: This would appear to be a problem within the system dlls on the windows 7 machine. With #Oyvind, the correct version of the .net framework is a good place to start, making sure that it is the same version as works on XP. But it does not look like your code.

Comment: How do I know if I got the correct version of .net framework? Is it different if I get them from Windows 7 updates? @Schroedingers Cat

Comment: No the version should be the same ( sorry, my comment and yours crossed ).

Comment: @Corbee : Is it start at all?

Comment: @CharithJ: yes it does start, it only crashes at specific conditions

Answer (score 3):

Try ThreadExceptionEventHandler and see.

```
 Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod)

    private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
    {
        //Exception handling...
    }
```

Edit : In Windows Forms applications, when an exception is thrown anywhere in the application (on the main thread or during asynchronous calls), you can catch it by registering for the ThreadException event on the Application.

**EDIT 2**

Try with compatibility? If it works fine, then there is something that doesn't compatible with Win7.
[image]

Comment: I tried application.unhandledexception with no luck, I'll check if I get lucky with this.

Comment: @Corbee : this should catch the exception if the application loads at all. Is it start?

Comment: My app does start. I'm going to try it once I get to my workplace.

Comment: @Corbee : Is so, hopefully this will catch the exception.

Comment: @ Corbee : Do you register the TheadException event handler in the main method? If the application starts and crash this should catch the exception. If not very strange...

Comment: Yup I did, no warning at all, just crashes.

Comment: @ Corbee : Sorry to see that still you have this issue. The only thing that I can suggest you do check whether there is any security/permission issues. Because it works in XP, try to run the app as Administrator. Right click on the exe and select "Run as Administrator" and see...

Comment: @ Corbee : I've edited the answer. Try with Compatibility feature on Win7

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to run the program in [Windows XP compatibility mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/)

Comment: It's a nice idea, I'll try this as the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

`Faulting module name: ntdll.dll` says you're in for a lot of fun, but you should start with any P/Invokes in your code. It shouldn't be possible to cause such an error from .NET, so it's some native DLL you're calling.

P/Invoke lets you call normal, native, non-managed executables from managed code. This can be anything that isn't programmed in .NET - i.e. drawing libraries, audio libraries, etc. It is possible that you use it without knowing, for example, if you have multimedia controls. There's a pretty decent article [right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

If you're doing COM Interop with i.e. Microsoft Office, the same as above applies. Check if it's the same Office version, and even if it is, you may need the same versions of the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) from Microsoft.

You may also try starting the application from Visual Studio, you might get a stack trace, which tells you the exact path the application took before crashing. Then you'll know what's happening.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does P/Invokes mean? @Vladislav Zorov

Comment: I've added some more explanations and debugging ideas :) Sorry for assuming everyone knows everything :)

Comment: Most of my codes are Access related, so I don't have P/Invoke involved

Comment: If by "Access" you mean Microsoft Access, then yes, there *is* P/Invoke involved. It's done behind the scenes for you. Your problem is most probably there - different Office versions, no PIAs installed, etc.

Comment: @Vladislav Zorov: Yes, I meant Microsoft Access Oledb. I downloaded Primary Interop Assemblies? What's the next step?